# Input listando resultado de consulta cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Olá, estou tentando listar um resultado de um consulta do meu controller em um input, mas está retornando zero, mas quando dou `print_r`, ele me retorna toda array, o que tem de errado?

Controller:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Foto->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Recipe Saved!');
            $this->render('add');
        }
    }
    $acomodacoes = $this->Navigation->find('list');
    $this->set('acomodacoes',$acomodacoes);
    print_r($acomodacoes); // estou dando esse print_r só para ver se realmente existe um array
}
```

Meu form:

```
<?= $this->Form->create('Galeria.Foto',array('type' => 'file')); ?>
<fieldset>            
    <legend><?= __('Adicionar Galeria de fotos'); ?></legend>
     <strong> Hot? </strong>
    <?=  $this->Form->checkbox('hot', array('value' => 1)); ?>
    <?=  $this->Form->input('acomodacoes',array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
    <?=  $this->Form->input('titulo',array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>
    <?=  $this->Form->input('descricao',array('class' => 'form-control')); ?>                
    <?=  $this->Form->input('Imagem', array('type' => 'file')); ?>

</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit',array('class' => 'form-control'))); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

É preciso informar o *array* **$acomodacoes** no *input* relacionado. E sendo várias opções, você precisa das propriedade `type` e `options`:

```
$this->Form->input('acomodacoes', array(
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $acomodacoes)
);
```

Para as opções, você terá como `value` o **id** do item, e caso o seu *Model* tenha definido o [`displayField`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#displayfield), será este o texto exibido.